# How to grab ASP.NET Web Api token (login) from a JS fetch and save token

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a React client to interact with my Asp.Net WebAPI (.NET Framework). I can succesfully register, and post data to the database (if I hard code the token in).

When "logging in" through postman it's http://localhost:44331/token with "grant_type, username, password". How can I write a fetch in JS to login and grab the token and save the token in my React app.

Here's my current fetch:

```html
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://localhost:44331/token", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: grant_type,
        username: username,
        password: password,
      }),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

P.S. I'm realatively new to JS and C#.

Answer (score 0):

paul7,

The knowledge about data storing is helpful in this scope of activity.
I recommend take some info about possibility of get info both in fe and be sides.

Some alternatives are:

- SessionStorage
- LocalStorage
- Cookies
- Cache

---

All of them have application and differ in technical details.

---

Return to your question - i suggest just save Your token to localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
```

where `data.token` is your property.

The following functions may be useful in these operations (cause
sometimes You have to do various transformations before retrieving data from the clipboard.):

- JSON.stringify() - converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string
- JSON.parse() - method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string

Comment: So would I just set "localStorage.setItem("token", data.token); in the promise resolver?

Comment: Glad to help if helped

Comment: Yes - when everything on server side come correctly - You Can simply evaluate by assign to that line variable and add console.log. Later U using localstorage.getItem

Comment: Okay cool, makes sense. I currently get a 400 error code with login. But token makes sense.